# More thane one NewSavebox fails compilation

Tags: latex, tikz

The following code has a problem with the second `\newsavebox{\spec}`. It does not compile. However if I use twice the `\speciesone`, i.e.:

```latex
\matrix [matrix of nodes] {
\node (species1) [shape=rectangle,draw] {\usebox{\speciesone}}; & \node (species2) [shape=rectangle,draw] {\usebox{\speciesone}};\\
};
```

I have no problem.

```latex
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,table,10pt,yellow,mathserif]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\newsavebox{\speciesone}
\sbox{\speciesone}{
\begin{tabular}{c c c c}
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{{$k~ \times $  1}} \tabularnewline
  \hline
  $\vec{v} =$ &  $v_{1}$ & $v_{2}$ & $v_{3}$ \tabularnewline
  \hline
  \hline
  & $\circ$ & $\circ$ & $\circ$ \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
}

\newsavebox{\spec}
\sbox{\spec}{
\begin{tabular}{c c c c}
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{{$k~ \times $  2}} \tabularnewline
  \hline
  $\vec{v} =$ &  $v_{1}$ & $v_{2}$ & $v_{3}$ \tabularnewline
  & $\circ$ & $\circ$ & $\circ$ \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes] {
\node (species1) [shape=rectangle,draw] {\usebox{\speciesone}}; & \node (species2) [shape=rectangle,draw] {\usebox{\spec}};\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid *Undefined control sequence...* errors, you should cut `\begin{document}` and paste it **before** both

```
\newsavebox{\speciesone}
\sbox{\speciesone}{
...
}
```

and

```
\newsavebox{\spec}
\sbox{\spec}{
...
}
```